# Unrecognised \thesection, \thesubsection, \topmargin, \headstep and \headheight

Tags: highlighting, texstudio

I am using LaTeX for first time. However, I am writing a report based on someone else's.
I have noticed that TeXStudio does not recognise:

```
\thesection
\thesubsection
\topmargin
\headstep
\headheight
```

They appear to be highlighted in orange and a small reading saying "Unrecognized command" appears when the cursor is placed over them.
Hence, I am pretty much limited to do not modify the format of my heads and foots when using `fancyhdr`.

The following is one part of the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}.0}
\renewcommand*\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}

\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{15pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{11pt}

\begin{document}
\input{./titlepage.tex}

\lhead{Whatever I want as the head}
\rhead{\rightmark}
\lfoot{Whatever I want as the foot}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\cfoot{}
```

This, however, produces well numbered sections and subsections (1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.1, 3.2, etc) and the right head as the title of the section.

The problem is that I cannot change the the length of the head and foots, as any value inserted in `\headheight` does not produce any change at all.

Any idea about what am I doing wrong?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you. A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit.

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: TeXStudio doesn't know about *all* legal commands; the `\headheight` should be at least 14.5pt as a message in the log file tells you.

Comment: I deleted what @egreg edited because I did not know how these threads work. Now I do.

So the heads cannot be smaller than 14.5pt at all? Is there any other command/code to edit the heads (font, size, etc)?

Comment: @Alejo The head needs to be at least 14.5pt high based on the font setup and the material you want to put in it.